How to parse 'LYS_ANYXML' data using libyang
I have a YANG data that I wish to parse, which is printed as:
<get xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <data>
    <sync xmlns="urn:o-ran:sync:1.0">
      <sync-status>
        <sync-state>LOCKED</sync-state>
        <supported-reference-types>
          <item>PTP</item>
        </supported-reference-types>
        <supported-reference-types>
          <item>SYNCE</item>
        </supported-reference-types>
      </sync-status>
    </sync>
  </data>
</get>

This is stored as a part of the lyd_node op, I can print this data using lyd_print_file(), but when I try to get the sync-state only using the lyd_child() function, it shows NULL.
The schema of the data node here is LYS_ANYXML, and I'd like to parse this type of YANG data by storing its sync-state into a variable.

There are several approaches to storing the leaf sync-state in a variable as per the documentation of libyang.
The key is type-casting, because of the anyxml type as you mentioned. An example code follows:
/* assuming the data has already been parsed and op is the node <get> */
struct lyd_node_any *data = (struct lyd_node_any *)lyd_child(op); // <data>
struct lyd_node *tree = data->value.tree; // <sync>
struct lyd_node *sync_state;
LY_ERR r = lyd_find_path(tree, "/xml-ns:sync/sync-status/sync-state", 0, &sync_state); // fill in the correct XML namespace
if (!r) {
    printf("Value of the node %s is %s\n", LYD_NAME(sync_state), lyd_get_value(sync_state));
}

In this case, once you have the tree variable, traversing the actual data can be done in multiple ways and doing so by calling lyd_find_path() as shown is one of them.
